# Long lived resource access

Tags: python, python-packaging, python-importlib

I'm trying to package an application with some data in the structure. This application will perform a series of queries to DDBB and finally generate a script that will be launched to a batch system (SLURM). The script will be based on a template (part of the resources I'm accessing) and will refer to some helper scripts that will also be packed as resources:

```
./
  src/
      package/
              __init__.py
              code.py
              templates/
                        job.tmplt
              helpers/
                      helper1.sh
                      helper2.sh
```

According to Python manual, resources should be accessed like:

```
from importlib.resources import as_file, files

template_in = files("package.templates") / "job.tmplt"
helper_base = as_file(files("package.helpers"))

cmd = Path("job.cmd")
with template_in.open("r") as tmplt_in, cmd.open("w") as job_out:
    print(f"{helper_base.resolve()}/helper1.sh", file=job_out)
```

But that does not work. `helper_base` is not a real `Path` object and fails to return the real path name. I understand that this is because it could be inside a zip file and the `importlib.resources` is facilitating me the access to the file (and posterior cleanup, if needed). But my use case is different: I need just a reference to the file, and that reference be valid long after the script finishes (as it will be used by the batch system).

Is there any way to get the clean path to a resource that is not encapsulated in any container (like a zip) so it can be accessed after the script is finished?

Comment: Your should decide on a location where the resource should be placed on hard drive (use [_`platformdirs`_](https://pypi.org/project/platformdirs/)). Your code should take care of checking that the resource exists at that location, if not then the code should copy the resource from the package (with `importlib.resources`) into that path, then use this on-disk copy.

Comment: Ouch! No way of using the packaged data directly??? :'(

Comment: If the resource should outlive the script, then I guess not. At least no solution that I can think of. -- Maybe the resource file could be extracted to a "temporary" file, this way at least it would be deleted at some later point, but would still be available long enough, maybe. -- Otherwise you might also want to take into account that the cases where the Python code (and its package data resources) is used in zipped form are actually quite rare, as far as I know, maybe not even worth considering.

Comment: If I have to extract to a temporary file, the it makes no sense. It is better to extract to a final destination outside the package.
I will copy those files to a folder, then. Fortunately, they are few and small, but It looks like a waste of space and extra superfluous organization.
Thanks for the pointer to `platformdirs`! I was using package `xdg` for basic folder management, but your alternative looks far superior!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @sinoroc commented, there's no way to do that. The best approach is to have a "setup/installation" step where the data is copied from the package to a destination in disk outside the package (typically $XDG_DATA_HOME/$APPLICATION).

The code I used for that is:

```
from pathlib import Path
from importlib.resources import files

from platformdirs import user_data_path


def _get_data_dir(application: str) -> Path:
    data_dir = user_data_path(application)
    if not data_dir.exists():
        data_dir.mkdir(parents=True)

    return data_dir


def _populate_data_dir(data_dir: Path, package: str, force: bool = False) -> None:
    for file in files(package).iterdir():
        destination = data_dir / file.name
        if force or not destination.exists():
            with destination.open("w", encoding="UTF-8") as f_destination:
                f_destination.write(file.read_text())


_populate_data_dir(_get_data_dir("myapp"), "my_package")
```

This code assumes that there are no folder in the package dir (otherwise, you will have to process them defferently) and that the files to be copied are small (as they are read entirely into memory).